# Integrating Google Analytics OAuth with multiple client domains

Tags: php, oauth, cross-domain, google-analytics-api

I've written a service which runs on the clients own domain, but we retain the access to the source code. One of the features I am hoping to implement is the ability to view your Google Analytics within the backend of the system, and I have written a script with uses Google's OAuth to authenticate the user.

However, the problem I am facing is that each installation of the software has its own unique domain, so when Google checks the REDIRECT URI it is invalid.

I've read other posts on here which state if your domain is dynamic you can use the 'state' parameter to get around this, but I think this problem goes further than just being dynamic.

Has anyone else encountered this/know of any solution to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to treat this as an Installed App, so you should follow the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) instructions.

The flow would basically be that instead of a redirect back to your app (which you can't do) the user would copy and paste a code from Google into your application which would then authenticate them and authorize the app.

Comment: Perfect! I'll give this ago!